# Google Sheets API - Find and Replace - Also search within links

Tags: google-sheets-api

When you insert a URL into a cell it automatically gets a link attached to it.

If you use GUI Find and Replace command there is a checkbox "Also search within links" but API [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest) doesn't have this option. As a result, the link is not updated.

How can I update both text and the link when search and replace with API?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to find a word inside the hyper link?

Comment: @GiselleValladares In fact I replace the whole link, and it is the only text in the cell.

Comment: I found an option for you. I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to add hyperlinks using formulas. I'm using python for the sample since you didn't specify the programming language you are using. However, it should be a similar process for most of them.

Since find replace doesn't allow you to add a hyperlink, you can add one by replacing the test with a formula.

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

sheet = service.spreadsheets()

# request to call find and replace the text 
# I was searching for the word Silver and replacing it with the formula
# =HYPERLINK("www.google.com" , "test") which add the URL "www.google.com"  
# and the word "test"        
batch_update_request = {
    "requests": [
        {
        "findReplace": {
            "find": "Silver",
            "replacement": '=HYPERLINK("www.google.com" , "test")',
            "allSheets":  True
        }
        }
    ]
}

#batch update request
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, 
                                                body=batch_update_request)
response = request.execute()
```

**Reference:**

- [HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313)

Comment: Really works, thank you. Let it be the workaround till Google have fixed its API.

Comment: I'm glad that this workaround helped you! About the missing feature, you can requested from Google directly by following the information in this Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#developer_product_feedback)